# Is there a way in golang to replace all CR and LF line endings in a byte array?

Tags: go, compression, newline, data-manipulation

I am trying to create two separate functions in golang, one that is able to replace any CR line endings (\r) with \u00A0 and any LF line endings (\n) with \u00A1, and a second that is able to reverse the original function, or restore the CR and LF line endings later on.

It should also be noted, that data I am working with, has been read from a file, encrypted, and then compressed. I am trying to just get all the data on one line, so I can later read a file line by line to decompress and decrypt the file's chunks.

I have previously tried these two functions, that convert the byte array to a string, and replace parts of the string, but the after dumping the byte array to a file, it still had multiple CR and LF line endings.

```golang
func removeLineBreaks(input []byte) []byte {
    str := strings.Replace(string(input), "\r", "\u00A0", -1)
    str = strings.Replace(str, "\n", "\u00A1", -1)
    return []byte(str)
}

func restoreLineBreaks(input []byte) []byte {
    str := strings.Replace(string(input), "\u00A0", "\r", -1)
    str = strings.Replace(str, "\u00A1", "\n", -1)
    return []byte(str)
}
```

I have also tried the following two functions, and still have multiple CR and LF line endings.

```golang
func removeLineBreaks(input []byte) []byte {
    output := make([]byte, 0, len(input))
    for i := 0; i < len(input); i++ {
        if input[i] == '\r' {
            output = append(output, '\u00A0')
        } else if input[i] == '\n' {
            output = append(output, '\u00A1')
        } else {
            output = append(output, input[i])
        }
    }
    return output
}

func restoreLineBreaks(input []byte) []byte {
    output := make([]byte, 0, len(input))
    for i := 0; i < len(input); i++ {
        if input[i] == '\u00A0' {
            output = append(output, '\r')
        } else if input[i] == '\u00A1' {
            output = append(output, '\n')
        } else {
            output = append(output, input[i])
        }
    }
    return output
}
```

The thing I was mainly expecting, was to be able to view all the data on one line, without any new line endings (CR, LF, or CR LF), that way I can process the data the way I intended later on.

Comment: Both versions of `removeLineBreaks` remove `\r` and `\n` from the data.  Post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I added some test code as an answer, yes both versions of the functions work, I just was not using them properly, I was not assigning the returned value to an actual value, I was just running the function to remove the lines. Life as a programmer...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my problem, the reason I was not getting the bytes returned as I wanted, was because I did not actually put anything for the function to return the value to.

```
byteChunk = removeLineBreaks(byteChunk)
```

The above two functions work as they should, here is the resulting code I used to test that everything worked the way it should:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"os"
"strings"
"github.com/google/brotli/go/cbrotli"
)

func main() {
    byteChunk := []byte("hello world\rThis is a test\r\nFor removing lines\nHello\r\nWorld")
    fmt.Printf("Original:\n%s\n\n", byteChunk)
    compressedChunk, err := cbrotli.Encode(byteChunk, cbrotli.WriterOptions{Quality: 11})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Compressed:\n%s\n\n", compressedChunk)
    removedLines := removeLineBreaks(compressedChunk)
    fmt.Printf("Removed Lines:\n%s\n\n", removedLines)
    restoredLines := restoreLineBreaks(removedLines)
    fmt.Printf("Restored Lines:\n%s\n\n", restoredLines)
    decompressedChunk, err := cbrotli.Decode(restoredLines)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Decompressed:\n%s\n\n", decompressedChunk)
}

func removeLineBreaks(input []byte) []byte {
    str := strings.Replace(string(input), "\r", "\u00A0", -1)
    str = strings.Replace(str, "\n", "\u00A1", -1)
    return []byte(str)
}

func restoreLineBreaks(input []byte) []byte {
    str := string(input)
    str = strings.Replace(str, "\u00A0", "\r", -1)
    str = strings.Replace(str, "\u00A1", "\n", -1)
    return []byte(str)
}
```